# How to know programly if my Android device has a mouse connected?

Tags: android

My app has some features which should not appear unless the device is connected with a mouse. but seems no APIs to detect the mouse existence?

Comment: http://www.pocketmagic.net/android-overlay-cursor/#.UckAcZwxSd4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [InputManager.InputDeviceListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/input/InputManager.InputDeviceListener.html) to detect whether there's a mouse connected. The class listens for changes in input devices.

Comment: Thank you so much yushulx! Iterating with InputDevice.getSources() is already good enough for me:)